# Windows Phone 8 network information

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am trying to get some information about the network like Network type, Network status, Cell ID, MCC, MNC, LAC, BID, NID, SID, Signal strength, Operator name.

The only thing I can get now is the mobile operator name using:

```
  using Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation;
  System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();            

  sb.Append("Mobile operator:  ");
  sb.AppendLine(DeviceNetworkInformation.CellularMobileOperator);
```

Like that I can get if WiFi is available, roaming available, just true or false.
Is there any solution to get some of the other information, network type for example if it's GSM - CDMA for example?

Also looking for the wifi network list, spots available and get the list.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can only get information for the currently connected network interfaces, not any other hotspots or cellular towers or their signal strength. You can't force the phone to change the connections either.

You *can* tell if you're on GSM or CDMA or WiFi and at what speed you're connected, and whether you're roaming.

See [this page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202867%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), and specifically this [linked page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh487166%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) for a walk-through of the available APIs.

You can get the Network type (GSM/CDMA/WiFi) from `Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkType` (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation.networkinterfaceinfo%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)).

The code snippet to get the `NetworkInformation` objects is:

```
private void UpdateNetworkInterfaces()
{
    NetworkInterfaces.Clear();
    NetworkInterfaceList networkInterfaceList = new NetworkInterfaceList();
    foreach (NetworkInterfaceInfo networkInterfaceInfo in networkInterfaceList)
    {
        NetworkInterfaces.Add(networkInterfaceInfo.InterfaceName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i will check the links.

Comment: Do you know some solution to get the network type?, GSM or CDMA for example.

Comment: do i need to use Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkType with "using". because after Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation. there is nothing else, if i put the full line shows an error in NetworkType

Comment: I don't quite understand your question - you need to use the code snippet, then you can call `networkInterfaceInfo.InterfaceType` inside the foreach loop. If in doubt use the `var` keyword and then you can see what type is being used.

Comment: Hi, don't forget you can vote for add features for new Windows Phone update! For the RIL I create a topic [here](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-dev-platform/suggestions/2912629-implement-radio-interface-layer-)! thanks!!