# How to catch signal strength in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want to find current signal strength of **GSM** network in windows phone and also want to find data network like 3G,2G. I got the operator name using `DeviceNetworkInformation.CellularMobileOperator` but I am not able to find signal strength. Is there any **API** to find strength and data network like **3G or 2G**?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Phone 8 network information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13968680/windows-phone-8-network-information)

Comment: Thanks for reply I saw this link, but my problem is not solved. How to get signal strength?

Comment: @Ajay - You cannot get the signal strength unfortunately.

Comment: @keyboard there is no any way to get signal strength ?

Comment: @Ajay - No, sorry. You can get the type of network connection (detailed in Paul's link) but not how strong the signal is.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot do that with the Windows Phone API.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no information available beyond basic carrier metadata in the SDK.

Beyond the information purposes (users already see the signal strength anyway), you should not adapt your app behavior based on such an indicator.