# API or Class to find out whether the HotSpot is turned on or not?

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I'm working over the "HotSpot" is the there any Api or Class whether is "HotSpot is Turned ON or Not".

Answer (score 0):

You could simply identify the `Wifi` status by using the [DeviceNetworkInformation.IsWiFiEnabled Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation.devicenetworkinformation.iswifienabled%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) . However you'll not be able to identify any `HotSpot` which is the `Internet Sharing` feature in WP.

Another point which i would like mention here is that, you could not programmatically turn on or off the `Wifi` status up to now, but you could simply allow the user to change it via `ConnectionSettingsTask`.
[Turn Windows Phone Settings On/Off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17145135/)

You could refer these for more:

[Windows Phone 8 network information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13968680/)

[Detect network changes for Windows Phone 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh487166%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)